# Повторение анимации

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Как сделать чтобы объект двигался с координаты 100,100 в координату 100,200, а потом возвращался без анимации в начальное положение и начинал движение cнова?

Answer (score 1):

```
     CABasicAnimation *animation =
         [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
     animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
     animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 200.0)];
     animation.duration = 5.0;
     animation.repeatCount = 0; // повторять бесконечно
     animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]; // замедлить в конце
     [viewToAnimate.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: Вот так я решил:
SKAction *ac = [SKAction moveToY:200 duration:0.3];
SKAction *ac2 = [SKAction moveToY:100 duration:0];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[ac, ac2]];
[BackG runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence]];

Comment: а ну есть речь а SpriteKit - тогда конечно только так